# How to add a y=x line in a scatterplot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, line, scatter-plot

I have an ascii file i with two variables and I want to create a scatterplot and add the line y=x in the scatterplot. The code for creating the scatterplot is below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

val1 = np.loadtxt(i, usecols=0)
val2 = np.loadtxt(i, usecols=1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
fig.set_size_inches(6, 6)
plt.scatter(val1, val2)
plt.savefig(outfile, bbox_inches='tight', format='png', dpi=200)
```

How to define the plot of line `y = x` without define the axis scale? Because the scale of the axes is dynamic based on the data. I want to do that for multiple files.

Comment: `plt.plot(val1, val1)` might work

Comment: @MSH. No it won't

Answer (score 2):

While there are such things as [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html) and [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html), and their less popular, but more general, sibling [`plt.axline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axline.html). You can specify a pair of points, or a starting point and a slope to draw an infninite line:

```
plt.axline([0, 0], slope=1)
```

Another approach is to draw a line in the region of your data:

```
xmin = val1.min()
xmax = val1.max()
ymin = val2.min()
ymax = val2.max()
xmargin = 0.1 * (xmax - xmin)
ymargin = 0.1 * (ymax - ymax)
margin = 0.5 * (xmargin + ymargin)
cmin = max(ymin, xmin)
cmax = min(xmax, ymax)
plt.plot(*[[cmin - margin, cmax + margin]] * 2)
```

Both methods are shown below with `plt.axis('equal')` and the following dataset:

```
val1, val2 = np.random.uniform([10, 20], size=(100, 2)).T
```

[image]

Comment: What about the (rather new) function [ax.axline()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axline.html) which accepts a slope (or two points) as parameter?

Comment: Thank you. However I wanted to plot the line y=x. I tried the code but I didn't;t get the line.

Comment: @JohanC I tried also the ax.axline but the problem is that I do not know the scale of each dataset since I use it for different files

Comment: @Nat. This plots the line `y=x`. When you plot anything of the form `plt.plot([p1, p2], [p1, p2])`, that's clearly along the line `y=x`

Comment: @Nat. Are you looking for `plt.axis('equal')`? I can add that to the answer...

Comment: @Nat The scale isn't needed.  `ax.axline()` just goes from border to border.

Comment: @MadPhysicist  does plt.axis('equal') make the scale of the the two axes identical? This could help.

Comment: @Nat. See update. There's actually `axline`, which I never new about until now

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you. I tried axline as you suggested. However, how I could define that the bounds of the axes (min/max) to be the same?

Comment: @Nat. `axline` ignores bounds. If the line is visible, it's drawn, otherwise it's not. The bounds are from the other data. I suggest you run some examples to see how it works. There's no replacement for the hands on approach